# SQL query not show needed result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a SQL query where I have to query three tables (some of them twice) and I do not get the result I need:

I need to search in 'articles' for a search string ('tennis') and lookup a second table 'orderdetails' for these articles.
The hits show how much was ordered.

Now I need to check if these items were already delivered.
So I look up table 'orders' for the 'orderdetails' and look in the same table if these orders have a 'delivery'. 'orders' adn 'delivery' have a field which shows what kind it is.

So I have to check if a 'delivery' was forwarded by an 'order'.

Next check if this 'delivery' includes the 'article' and sum up the delivered articles.

If the number of delivered articles is lower than the number of ordered articles I want to show this record.

So far it works besides these items:
    - [SOLVED] thanks to HLGEM 'orders' without a 'delivery' are not shown at all
    - [SOLVED] 'orders' with the same amount as 'delivery' are shown but i don't want them to.

Here is what I have so far:

PrO: Process Order
PrD: Process Delivery
a:   ArticleItem
p:   processOrderItem
d:   deliveryItem

[updated the code]

```
SELECT 
    a.Articlenumber AS Article,
    PrO.Number AS Order, 
    PrD.Number AS Delivery,
    p.Amount AS Orderamount,
    SUM(d.Amount) AS Deliveryamount,
    (p.Amount - Deliveryamount) AS OpenAmount

FROM Article AS a
    INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails AS p
    ON  (a.ArticleNumber = p.Article)
        AND LEFT(p.Order, 3) = 'OR-'
    INNER JOIN Processes as PrO
    ON  PrO.Number = p.Order
        AND TEXTSEARCH('Delivery:' IN PrO.Forwarded)
    LEFT JOIN Processes as PrD
    ON  PrO.Nummer = PrD.ForwardedFrom
        AND LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-' 
    INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails as d
    ON  PrD.Number = d.Order
        AND d.Article = p.Article
WHERE (a.Categorie = 'tennis') 
GROUP BY(Article)
```

Adding the following line solved the second problem:

```
HAVING Deliveryamount < Orderamount
```

Comment: what doesn't work about the query?  Please generate a sql fiddle for us:  sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I don't see a numeruic comparison line.  Should ````d.Article <> p.Article```` or something like that?

Comment: Something like the last line above GROUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.Articlenumber AS Article,        
    PrO.Number AS Order, 
    PrD.Number AS Delivery,    
    p.Amount AS Orderamount,    
    SUM(d.Amount) AS Deliveryamount,    
    (p.Amount - Deliveryamount) AS OpenAmount    
FROM Article AS a    
    INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails AS p ON (a.ArticleNumber = p.Article)   
    INNER JOIN Processes as PrO ON PrO.Number = p.Order
    LEFT JOIN Processes as PrD ON PrO.Nummer = PrD.ForwardedFrom AND LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-'
    INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails as d ON PrD.Number = d.Order
WHERE (a.Categorie = 'tennis') 
AND LEFT(p.Order, 3) = 'OR-'
AND TEXTSEARCH('Delivery:' IN PrO.Forwarded)AND d.Article = p.Article
GROUP BY(Article)
```

This will fix your left join problem.

Comment: This is heading the right direction. I am getting everything I want, but it still shows the line if SUM(s.Article)=p.Article. Which should not happen

Comment: And I found the solution: adding 'HAVING Orderamount > Deliveryamount' solved the problem with the already devlivered it all. :)

Comment: @HLGEM sir, is textsearch a mysql function? I don't find it in google, can you tell me more about it?

Comment: @jcho360  I don't know, I was just fixing one problem that I saw. And BTW I am not a sir.

Answer (score 1):

I have no Idea what is this line in the where condition:

`AND TEXTSEARCH('Delivery:' IN PrO.Forwarded)`

I don't think that `textsearch` function exist in mysql, so try this:

```
 SELECT 
        a.Articlenumber AS Article,        
        PrO.Number AS Order, 
        PrD.Number AS Delivery,    
        p.Amount AS Orderamount,    
        SUM(d.Amount) AS Deliveryamount,    
        (p.Amount - Deliveryamount) AS OpenAmount    
    FROM Article AS a    
        INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails AS p ON (a.ArticleNumber = p.Article)   
        INNER JOIN Processes as PrO ON PrO.Number = p.Order
        LEFT JOIN Processes as PrD ON PrO.Nummer = PrD.ForwardedFrom    
        INNER JOIN ProcessesDetails as d ON PrD.Number = d.Order
    WHERE (a.Categorie = 'tennis') 
    AND LEFT(p.Order, 3) = 'OR-'
    AND PrO.Forwarded like '%Delivery:%'
    AND LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-' 
    AND d.Article = p.Article
    GROUP BY(Article)
```

try using `AND PrO.Forwarded like '%Delivery:%'` instead of `AND TEXTSEARCH('Delivery:' IN PrO.Forwarded)`

Comment: it shows the same result. But you are right, this looks easier to read. Thanks for that one.
Still I have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is possibly related to these two lines:

```
LEFT JOIN Processes as PrD ON PrO.Nummer = PrD.ForwardedFrom
```

and

```
AND LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-'
```

because the left join effectively has NULL values if there is no delivery there is no way that the PrD.Number can start with 'DE-'.  It's possible that a where clause like:

```
AND (PrD.Number is null OR LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-')
```

Might solve the first part of your question. Not sure about the second part of the question. I can't figure out where you're doing the numeric comparison.

Comment: this would only change something if I would change the whole block:
    AND ( TEXTSEARCH('Delivery:' IN PrO.Forwarded) OR
    (LEFT(PrD.Number,3) = 'DE-' 
    AND d.Article = p.Article)
)
But then I receive the wrong number summed up of delivered items.